# send selected item value to server with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a `dropdown` and the items of the `dropdown` Filling dynamic,
i looking for a way to send selected value to server **using php not ajax**
i have a `<form>` and submit button,
have to access the selected value on server,
this is my code:

```
<form action="singer.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>سبک</td>
      <td><select name="genre_list">
          <?php
  include('../db_inc.php');
$sql="select * from genre";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $option =$row->genre_name;
    $value =$row->genre_id;
    echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';

    }
?>

        </select></td>

  </table>
</form>
```

i'm googled this issue but i can't find the solution,

Comment: PHP is a server-side thing, AJAX is a client-side one. They are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit to the current file, you will see the selected form by using `$_POST['genre_list']`

If you want to send the user selected value, you should check where does `$_POST['genre_list']` appears at the `while-loop` and then add to his `<option>` the attribute `selected="selected"` so it should look like

```
$isSelected = ($_POST['genre_list'] == $row['COLUMN-NAME'] ? "selected='selected' " : "");
echo '<option $isSelected value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';
```

**Do not forget** to avoid SQL-Injection when getting values from user client.

Answer (score 1):

have it output the variable for the value surrounded with quotes `"`

```
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$option.'</option>';
```

then use: `$_POST['genre_list']` to show the selected genre_id

Answer (score 1):

In singer.php, `$_POST['genre_list']` should contain the value from the SELECT.